# Can Spark Cassandra Connector resolve hostnanmes from headless service in K8S environment?

Tags: kubernetes, cassandra, datastax, spark-cassandra-connector

Datastax Spark Cassandra Connector takes "spark.cassandra.connection.host" for connecting to cassandra cluster.

1. Can we provide headless service of C* cluster on K8S environment as host to this parameter("spark.cassandra.connection.host").
2. Will it resolve the contact points?
3. What is the preferred way of connecting with C* cluster on the K8s environment with Spark Cassandra Connector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, SCC resolves all provided contact points into IP addresses on the first connect, and then only uses these IP addresses for reconnection. And after initial connection happened, it discover the rest of the cluster. Usually this is not a problem as SCC should receive notifications about nodes up & down and track nodes IP addresses.   But in practice, it could happen that nodes are restarted too fast, and notifications are not received, so Spark jobs that use SCC could stuck trying to connect to the IP addresses that aren't valid anymore - I hit this multiple times on the DC/OS.

This problem is solved with the [release of SCC 2.5.0](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2020/05/advanced-apache-cassandra-analytics-now-open-all) that includes a fix for [SPARKC-571](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/SPARKC-571). It introduced a new configuration parameter - `spark.cassandra.connection.resolveContactPoints` that when it's set to `false` (`true` by default) will always use hostnames of the contact points for both initial connection & reconnection, avoiding the problems with changed IP addresses.

So on K8S I would try to use this configuration parameter with just normal Cassandra deployment.

Comment: Yes Alex I saw this parameter (spark.cassandra.connection.resolveContactPoints) in the documentation. But I wanted to know that is SCC able to resolve contact points from headless service. I believe yes as Rico has also mentioned in previous answer.

Comment: It will resolve, yes - but then it will continue to use discovery of the nodes themselves, and I'm not sure how it will play well with it.  Depending on the operator used, you may not need to have headless service

Answer (score 1):

Yes, why not. There is a [good example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/cassandra/) on the Kubernetes official documentation. You create a [headless service with a selector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#with-selectors):

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: cassandra
  name: cassandra
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - port: 9042
  selector:
    app: cassandra
```

and basically when you specify `spark.cassandra.connection.host=cassandra` (in the same K8s namespace, otherwise, you have to provide Cassandra..svc.cluster.local` it will resolve to the Cassandra contact points (the Pod IP addresses where Cassandra is running)

✌️

Comment: Any restriction with version? I was not able to find in documentation of Datastax spark cassandra connector.